# pgfplots: Plot around a Pole of a rational function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to use `pgfplots` to plot the function `(x-1.2)*(x-3)*(x-4.8)/((x-1)*(x-5))` for x-values from 0 to 6. However, pgfplots does not seem to want to show me the whole plot - it doesn't show anything for `x>5`. This should not be related to restricting the y to the domain `-10:10`, as the y values are within these bounds, cf. [1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%28%28x-1.2%29%2a%28x-3%29%2a%28x-4.8%29%2F%28%28x-1%29%2a%28x-5%29%29%2C+x%3D0+...+6%29).

Here's a minimal example with a deliberately high samplesize (to make sure the data isn't omitted due to lack of samples):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=5cm,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle, 
ylabel={$M(\lambda)$},
xmin=0, xmax=6, 
ytick=\empty, 
yticklabels={},
xtick={5,5.5}, 
xticklabels={5,5.5}]

\addplot[unbounded coords=jump, samples=10000, restrict x to domain=0:6,restrict y to  domain=-10:10, color=black, mark=none]{(x-1.2)*(x-3)*(x-4.8)/((x-1)*(x-5))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there some obvious mistake, or some hidden pitfalls in my effort?

Possibly related is the fact that the `xticks` and `xticklabels` are not set correctly.

Comment: I never would have guessed that this was related to the particular choice of `x=5`. A duplicate, indeed.